# Elm function with the type: Signal (List a) -> List (Signal a)

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am new to elm and functional programming in general. But I am using elm and I really need a function that has a Signal (List String) as an input and returns List (Signal String).

I know I probably shouldn't have this problem with a better architectural design in my program but having a function that could do this would solve a big problem for me.

The combine function does exactly the opposite:

```
combine : List (Signal a) -> Signal (List a)
combine = List.foldr (map2 (::)) (constant [])
```

I've tried to do something similar to the combine function but have been unsuccessful so far. Any ideas on how to create such function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This is not possible in general

The inverse of `combine` is not (in general) possible.
When you have a list of static size of signals, then you can `combine` them into a signal of lists of static size. But when you go the other way, there is no guarantee that the lists in the signal are a static size. Therefore you cannot "just" construct a list out of it.
(If you could then a normal value of type `List` could have a changing size without showing `Signal` around the type, and you would be dynamically creating and destroying signals in the list. Those are two things Elm disallows. )

## But with some restrictions...

Of course if *you* know that the list in the signal is of a static size, you can write a specific function based on that assumption; that function would then fail at runtime if the case occurs that your assumption of static size lists was wrong.

```
unsafe : Maybe a -> a
unsafeHead m =
  case m of
    Just a -> a
    Nothing -> Debug.crash "unsafe: You're out of luck. The `Maybe` was not a `Just`. "

uncombine : Int -> Signal (List a) -> List (Signal a)
uncombine n sig =
  if n == 0
    then []
    else Signal.map (List.head >> unsafe) sig
      :: uncombine (n-1) (Signal.map (List.tail >> unsafe) sig)
```

(I'm quite sure this question was discussed on the [elm-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elm-discuss) mailing list once, but I can't find it any more)

Comment: Thank you @Apanatshka for your answer. I understand that the list needs to be of static size, but because I am stubborn I wanted to keep trying and changed the uncombine function to this: 
`uncombine : Signal (List a) -> List (Signal a)
 uncombine sig = if (Signal.map isEmpty sig)
then [] else Signal.map (List.head >> unsafe) sig :: uncombine (n-1) (Signal.map (List.tail >> unsafe) sig)`.
But I get type mismatch error because the if clause want a Bool value but gets Signal Bool value. Is there some workaround to this problem?

Comment: No, there is no workaround. What you're attempting is impossible.